# How do I return a value in a promise? (Firebase.get())

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I've been struggling for the past four hours on this. I am writing a function to see if a property named "data" exists in my Firebase storage. If it does, I want to do one thing, if it doesn't I want to do something else. However, I cannot figure out how this asynchronous stuff works for the life of me. I simplified my code below. Basically I just want to wait for the data to be fetched before I reach the if/else. I've been playing around with different options but keep getting errors or some other issue. The code below is the closest I've gotten to working where the code doesn't crash but even if "data" does not exist in the Firestore, I'm always going through the else clause and I don't know why. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
const fetchDataFromDB = async (user) => {
  let query = db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      doc.data();
      console.log(doc.data().data);
    });

  return await query;
};

export const getSchedule = (miles, user) => {
  const firebaseData = fetchDataFromDB(user);
  console.log(firebaseData);

  // WAIT FOR FETCH BEFORE CONTINUING
  if (!firebaseData) {
    console.log("NOT getting data from FB");
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("getting data from FB");
    return;
  }
};
```

Comment: `fetchDataFromDB()` returns a promise as do all `async` functions

Comment: And the `then` in the `query` chain has no `return` so `await query` will resolve to undefined

Comment: Hi @Notorious776, did the below answer help you? what are you missing? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Hi @sllopis, I think for the most part it solved my issue. The biggest part is in my example code I was returning nothing but in reality, I want to return an array (which is what firebaseData is). This made it so when I called the function in my React component it would return a promise. I'm currently working through getting that sorted and I think I almost have it figured out.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you have any more questions, go ahead and ask. Note that new issues may warrant a new Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change up the code as follows:

```
const fetchDataFromDB = (user) => {
  return db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
};

export const getSchedule = async (miles, user) => {
  const firebaseData = await fetchDataFromDB(user);
  console.log(firebaseData);

  if (!firebaseData) {
    console.log("NOT getting data from FB");
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("getting data from FB");
    return;
  }
};
```

The point to remember about `async await` is that it doesn't really make asynchronous calls synchronous, it just makes them look that way so that your code is a bit less unwieldy with wrapped promises and the like. Every async function returns a promise, so if you want to deal with what it returns, you need to either deal with the promise directly (using `.then...`), or by using another `await`. In the latter case, you of course need to declare the consuming function as `async` as well.

With regards to the first function, there's no need for the `async await` there. Just return the promise. (Thanks @charlieftl for pointing out the problem in that code)

Comment: See my comment above about no return in `query` chain `then`. Adding to your answer would make it a one stop for OP

Comment: Thank you for your help @charlietfl and see sharper! My only issue now is I guess I made my example too simple. The function "getSchedule" is actually supposed to return an array which I want my React component's stat to be set to. However since the function is async, its returning yet another promise... Is there anyway I can just pass back the raw array from the getSchedule function?

Comment: Not sure I follow. An array is like any other object. Or do you mean you make more than one fetchData call?

Comment: So basically the getSchedule() function grabs two array from the Firestore database and I have two React states that I want to set equal to it. However when I call getSchedule() in my React Component, it returns a promise instead the arrays since getSchedule uses "async await" I think.

[This](https://pastebin.com/Qj2CyFz6) is part of my React component that is calling getSchedule(), but it throws an error since its returning a promise instead of the arrays. Hope I'm explaining it right. It feels like theres a simple solution to this but I can't figure it out..

Comment: Anywhere you have a promise returned, you can use await, so long as you declare the surrounding function async. So set the function inside your component to be async and use `await getSchedule(...)`.

Comment: Of course you need to make getSchedule `return firebaseData` as well.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding but I feel like I'm just going in circles here. [This](https://pastebin.com/ZNBaCWg1) is what my code looks like now but I am still getting errors. I put console.logs to see what order everything is coming out and [here](https://pastebin.com/ppuUQhpB) is what my console spits out. From the looks of it, "await" is not waiting for the promise to be resolved before continuing and is setting my states [milesArray, serviceArray] to the initial values of [milesArrayInit, serviceArrayInit]=null. The console prints the correct arrays after which is a step in right direction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217287/discussion-between-see-sharper-and-notorious776).